# How to know if preemption is happening on Yarn fair share scheduler?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

Is there any way to know for sure if the preemption mechanism has been triggered on YARN?

In the YARN Resource Manager or the logs maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your log level is set to `info` you should see this in the YARN Resource Manager logs.

```
            // Warn application about containers to be killed
            for (RMContainer container : containers) {
              FSAppAttempt app = scheduler.getSchedulerApp(
                      container.getApplicationAttemptId());
              LOG.info("Preempting container " + container +
                      " from queue " + app.getQueueName());
              app.trackContainerForPreemption(container);
            }
```

at [https://github.com/apache/hadoop/.../scheduler/fair/FSPreemptionThread.java#L143](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/resourcemanager/scheduler/fair/FSPreemptionThread.java#L143).

And if you have the log level to `debug` you will also see this:

```
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
      LOG.debug(
          "allocate: post-update" + " applicationAttemptId=" + appAttemptId
              + " #ask=" + ask.size() + " reservation= " + application
              .getCurrentReservation());

      LOG.debug("Preempting " + preemptionContainerIds.size()
          + " container(s)");
    }
```

at [https://github.com/apache/hadoop/.../scheduler/fair/FairScheduler.java#937](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/resourcemanager/scheduler/fair/FairScheduler.java#L937)